# css hover image swap and link?

Tags: css, hyperlink

I am making a site with rollover jpegs where the rollovers are clickable ads supporting the site. Not being a coder I used Dreamweaver's Behavior controls to create javascript rollovers, but the trouble with js is that IOS and Kindle do not support it.

And so the answer would be to use CSS hover code. I am having great difficulty finding a simple solution. On this test page the very top rollover "Flealess in Seattle" is done with CSS code, but my crude code of wrapping the div in   does not give the div a link. Directly below it is the js version that works fine:

[link url=http://tailsofhollywood.com/indexcss.html][/link]

(It also ignores the custom cursor change when in hover - but that is done with css too so I don't know what's going on there.)

what I need is for ALL the rollover jpegs on the page to have their own css code that works with the links I've put in, so I can remove the problematic js from the page. Any advice you can give would be greatly appreciated! I am not a coder - so please be gentle with me  [:)]

Comment: iOS definitely supports JavaScript. I'm unsure about Kindle (whether you mean the device or the reading app). Neither of them, though, supports CSS `:hover`.

Comment: Does the rollover image need to be clickable in its own right?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/2Wa46/2/ - basic version with a CSS Opacity effect for you :)

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://tailsofhollywood.com/Seattle400.jpg"></a>

a         { display: block; position: relative; }
a:after   {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; 
    top: 0;
    content: url(http://tailsofhollywood.com/Seattle400b.jpg);  
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.15s ease; 
}
a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle is broken.